# Keep CSS styles after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preventdefault

I have some `jQuery` code for my navbar that controls a dropdown and some other styling.  For testing purposes, I've made the first line:

```
$( ".dropdown--link").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

but this stops my link from functioning.  Is there a way to maintain the `jQuery` styling, and link to the new page while maintaining the added style?  For example, all styling **after** `event.preventDefault();` is removed after I navigate to the new page and I want it to remain (in the case where `preventDefault` is removed).

```
( ".dropdown--link").on("click", function(event) {
        // event.preventDefault();

        var targetPosition = $(this).offset().left;
        var targetWidth = $(this).width();
        var targetCenter = targetPosition + (0.5 * targetWidth) - 10;

        $( "nav ul li" ).each(function() { $(this).removeClass("bold"); });
        $(this).addClass('bold');
        $(".arrow-down").show();
        $(".arrow-down").css("left", targetCenter);
})
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are asking for. I don't see any navigation happening in your provided code. Navigating to a new page usually means the whole page is *reloaded* which means that any styling that you've set up is lost.

Comment: No there is no way in that code to do it. You would need to add code in the next page that will do what you want.

Comment: If you want to pass information to the next page to restyle the way you need it (as @epascarello said) you can pass a parameter in the URL of the link, or set a cookie for the session.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks my apologies for not including the link, but the link with class `.dropdown--link` links out to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the "status" of the style to local storage and every time you load a page change the style if it was changed previously.

```
function changeStyle() {
        // event.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem("styleChanged", "1");

        var targetPosition = $(this).offset().left;
        var targetWidth = $(this).width();
        var targetCenter = targetPosition + (0.5 * targetWidth) - 10;

        $( "nav ul li" ).each(function() { $(this).removeClass("bold"); });
        $(this).addClass('bold');
        $(".arrow-down").show();
        $(".arrow-down").css("left", targetCenter);
}

$(".dropdown--link").on("click", changeStyle);

$.ready(function(){
    var styleChanged = localStorage.getItem("styleChanged");
    if (styleChanged && styleChanged.equals("1")) {
        changeStyle();
    }
});
```

When you'll want to undo the change run this code:

```
localStorage.setItem("styleChanged", "0");
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it should work, but I think I am just approaching this problem wrong and should rethink using something like AngularJS

Comment: That is true for your project. But this answer solves your original question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want your navigation to indicate what tab is active at this moment,
You can easily achieve this by splitting your navigation from your content.
And only loading the content,

Take a look at. AngularJS, KnockoutJs, EmberJS. or even MVC from Microsoft.
they all allow you to have single page websites which refreshes just part of your page.

Hell you could just refresh the content in your page with an Ajax call if you want to.

Keeping state on another page would only work with url parameters or session variables.

Comment: Yeah, I've recently started to play with AngularJS, maybe thats what I should do